# Create date between consecutive dates

Tags: date, if-statement, join, sas, uniqueidentifier

I hope you can assist.

I have a SAS data set which has two columns, ID and Date which looks like this:
[image]
In some instances, the date column skips a month. I need a code which will create the missing date for each ID e.g. for AY273, I need a code that will create date 2022/11/20 and for WG163, 2022/12/15.

Comment: Is the day part of the month always constant for each ID?

Comment: No, It can vary but not by much. E.g. for the first ID the dates may vary between 18 - 22. The date is a premium collection date so it'll be based on the nearest workday but the dates i need to have created don't have to follow that rule

Comment: Ok. So regardless of the small variation, two dates can never occur within the same month in your data, correct?

Comment: Yes, each date will have a unique month

Comment: Shure? You will never have someone paying on `2022/01/30`, `2022/03/1`, `2022/03/30`, ... ?

Comment: I assume your input is ordered by `id` and `date`

Comment: You will never have to fill in two consecutive months for one id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the data with itself shifted one observation forward (to get a lead value) and loop across that range.

Example:

```
data have;
input id $ date yymmdd10.;
format date yymmdd10.;
datalines;
AAAAA 2021-11-20
AY273 2022-10-20
AY273 2022-12-20
AY273 2023-01-20
WG163 2022-10-15
WG163 2022-11-15
WG163 2023-01-15
ZZZZZ 2022-01-15
;

data want(keep=id date fillflag);
  merge have have(rename=(date=leaddate id=leadid) firstobs=2);

  if id eq leadid then
    do while (intck('month',date,leaddate) > 0);
      output;

      date = intnx('month',date,1,'sameday');
      fillflag = 1;
    end;
  else
    output;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
data WANT (drop = this_date last_date);
    set HAVE(rename=(date = this_date));
    by id;
    last_date = lag(this_date);
    if first.id then do;
        date = this_date;
        output;
    end;
    else do date = this_date to last_date + 16 by -30;
        output;
    end;

   format date yymmdd10.;
proc sort;
    by id date;
run;
```

If it does not work, I will correct it.